# Generating 32-bit/64-bit Eclipse CDT projects using CMake

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm setting up a C++ project which will be built for 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows and Ubuntu.  I'm using CMake 2.8.4 and, after having played with it for a few hours, got the VS2010 32-bit and 64-bit projects set up.  The problem I ran into is that the generator for Eclipse on the Ubuntu side (technically for Eclipse generators on all platforms), doesn't have separate versions for 32-bit/64-bit.

I realize that there's a GCC compiler switch to indicate which bit type you want (-m32, -m64) and I don't mind having separate solutions, but when I'm running cmake in the build directories, how do I tell it which one I want?  If there is no built-in way, is it possible to pass a custom variable/value, like `BITTYPE=64`, to the cmake command?  That way I could handle the rest in the CMakeLists.txt file with a simple if/else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Linux CMake looks at the compiler flags to determine if you are compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit. You can pass that information by setting the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` information upon running cmake:

```
cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-m32 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32
```

The portable way to determine if cmake is generating a 32-bit or 64-bit project then, is to query the [CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable%3aCMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P) variable, e.g.:

```
if (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
   # 64-bit project
else()
   # 32-bit project
endif()
```